# Using 'requests' library in Python Django 3.0.6

Tags: django, python-requests, python-3.6

I am trying to get some data using Django forms, the data is actually an *URL*, like this:

```
def sample(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = sampleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            RDS = form.cleaned_data['RDS']
            print(RDS)       
    form = sampleForm()
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

the url is in RDS variable. Now i want to use this url to make a GET request using *Requests* library of Python.
I tried adding these lines after the above code:

```
node_data = requests.get(RDS)    
print(node_data.content)
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help?

Comment: your second snippet seems to be missing something (get is not executed)

Comment: Sorry, i corrected it.

Comment: is the RDS variable having the protocol part? (http/https)
what's exactly in `node_data.content`?

Comment: Yes it contains the protocol part. It is something like: ```http://123.123.123.123:3211/x-nmos/query/v1.1/nodes```

At this moment ```node_data.content``` doesn't display anythinh but it should contain JSON data.

Comment: what's the status code of your response? (`node_data.status_code`)

Comment: Its was 503, some thing to do with the proxy settings and also my code's placement wasn't correct that is why it was not getting executed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Thanks everyone for your help.

```
def sample(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = sampleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            RDS = form.cleaned_data['RDS']
            print(RDS)
            response = requests.get(RDS)
            print(response.status_code)
            print(response.content)
    form = sampleForm()
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

Response:

```
http://123.123.123.123:3211/x-nmos/query/v1.1/nodes
200
{"JSON": "Data"}
```

Answer (score 1):

from the requests library [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/):

if `RDS` contains a url (including the protocol), a request can be made as follows:

```
response = requests.get(RDS)

# print result
print(response.status_code)
print(reponse.json())
```

Don't be afraid to read the docs! In this case, the index page contains exactly what you wanted to know.

PS: make sure the code gets executed

Comment: Code execution was one of the problems. Thanks for showing the way.